# How to find three dates are consecutive in an array of dates in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want a function from which I can identify the dates are consecutive or not.

```
const userArr1 = [
  { userid: "abc@email.com", doj: "2023-02-15T00:00:00.000Z" },
  { userid: "def@email.com", doj: "2023-02-16T00:00:00.000Z" },
  { userid: "pqr@email.com", doj: "2023-02-17T00:00:00.000Z" },
];
```

On passing this array in that function it should show dates are consecutive.

```
const userArr2 = [
  { userid: "abc@email.com", doj: "2023-02-10T00:00:00.000Z" },
  { userid: "def@email.com", doj: "2023-02-5T00:00:00.000Z" },
  { userid: "pqr@email.com", doj: "2023-02-12T00:00:00.000Z" },
];
```

On passing this array in that function it should show dates are not consecutive.

```
const userArr3 = [
  { userid: "abc@email.com", doj: "2023-01-31T00:00:00.000Z" },
  { userid: "def@email.com", doj: "2023-02-01T00:00:00.000Z" },
  { userid: "pqr@email.com", doj: "2023-02-02T00:00:00.000Z" },
];
```

On passing this array in that function it should show dates are consecutive.

I am unable to find the solution my expected solution is I want to find that the dates are consecutive or not.

Comment: What have you tried ? Do arrays alaways contain 3 objects ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I didnt try I am confused where to start it may contain more than 3 objects. It is just a example. I want to check if the dates are consecutive or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified the above answer and its working fine. I also added a new feature as it was required in my case. In that we can find no. of consecutive days you want to check.

```
const areDatesConsecutive = (userArr, noOfDays) => {
  if (userArr.length >= noOfDays) {
    for (let i = 1; i < userArr[noOfDays]; i++) {
      const diffInDays =
        (new Date(userArr[i].doj) - new Date(userArr[i - 1].doj)) / 86400000;

      if (diffInDays !== 1) return false;
    }
    return true;
  } else return false;
};
```